# How to add an ImageView over a Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, imageview

I want to add an ImageView within the `onClick()` of the Button. But the **ImageView should be aligned to the centre of the button.**

**How can I do this pragmatically?**

I'm creating a new instance of the ImageView to be added on top of the View that called it and it's position is equivalent of the View that called it.

**How can I get the X and Y coordinates?**

EDIT:

```
@Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
            if(v.getWidth() > v.getHeight()) size = v.getHeight();
            if(v.getWidth() < v.getHeight()) size = v.getWidth();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams button = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size,size);
            buttonc = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            buttonc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round);
            layout.addView(buttonc,button);
```

I'm using the above code to attempt to pragmatically set the size of the ImageView to that of the button, and it's working.

As for the coordinates, I still haven't figured it out.

To add clarity: I'm attempting to create a rounded ripple effect over the view that calls it.

Comment: create custom layout and assign this to button.

Comment: Can we see code which you are trying?

Comment: Sorry, the above code is working perfectly. I need help getting the position of the Button and setting the position of the ImageView accordingly.

Comment: Can't you use an ImageButton?

Comment: To add clarity, I'm attempting to build a ripple effect that will work on older API's, so it has to draw over the view that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a better solution create an image view before hand place it in the xml as you see fit,at first set its visibility to false .
On click switch its visibilty to true, and the image will appear

This solution is easier than what you are searching.

Feel free to ask questions

Comment: The problem with that is that my current implementation uses a TableLayout, so I don't think I can add the ImageView over the Button

Comment: Ok heres another suggestion set the image you want as the background of the button and simply when you press it: Replace the background to your image ,delete the text and make the button unclickable

Answer (score 0):

**to add Imageview**

```
@Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
    //LinearLayout
            LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

      //ImageView 
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
      //image resource
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.specs);
      //image position
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       //adding view to layout
            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
       //make visible to program
            setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```